# Custom type and Settings designer: designer won't write setting value to app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, designer, typeconverter, settings.settings

Here's what I want to do:

- Have an application-scoped Settings setting whose value is an array of a custom type
- Have the array of the custom type serialized to XML as opposed to a string
- Have the serialized value of my setting saved in app.config.

So far this is eluding me.

I have a custom type:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ServiceConfigurationConverter))]
[Serializable]
public class ServiceConfiguration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    // more
}
```

It has a custom TypeConverter that converts it back and forth from a string.  I wrote it that way because the examples I found were all for converting to strings, and because I'd be willing to serialize to a string if it meant that my values were being saved to app.config.  But as we will see, they aren't.

If I indicate (through editing the Settings.settings file directly) that the type of this setting is `MyNamespace.ServiceConfiguration[]`, I can enter XML manually to represent the array.  (I got the XML by writing a test that programmatically built the array and then serialized it using `XmlSerializer`.)  But, while this XML gets set in Settings.designer.cs as the default value for the setting, it doesn't get saved to app.config.

And that's problematic, because I want people to be able to see the property values in XML form in the the app.config, and be able to change them if need be.  If it's not written and read from the app.config, it's not run-time configurable.

If I manually create an entry in app.config, under `applicationSettings`, and enter in my serialized array as the setting's value, the settings designer asks me if I want to update the settings file value, and does so -- but removes the entry I put in under `applicationSettings`.

I'd be willing to consider writing some kind of designer for my custom type, if necessary, but I don't know what kind of designer that would be.

(I know that if I just changed the property type to "string" I could save the serialized XML as a string and avoid this whole problem.  But what I want is a property whose type is my custom type, not one I'd have to reconstitute.)

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the three goals at the top of this post with a custom type?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @RubberDuck  Nope.   I don't remember just what I did instead, but I never did solve that problem.

Comment: @RubberDuck  I did, however, figure out a few days ago that in VS 2015, I could successfully serialize to XML if I pasted the serialized XML into the Value field in the Settings editor. It was written as "serialize as XML" to app.config, and app.config changes were reflected in the deserialized object at run time.  BUT, I don't know whether that works with arrays or other collections.

Comment: For whatever it's worth @AnnL., I've just been putting the XML in the app config under the correct settings Node. I'm only reading the values, but works well enough for me. Just can't use the designer. I think we both came to the same solution, more or less.